# Nested routes work but others don't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Struggling with routing in Rails!

This works: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/locations/1/statistics` but `http://127.0.0.1:3000/locations/` does not work.

My routes look like this:

```
resources :locations do
    resources :statistics
end
```

I can get **only** `http://127.0.0.1:3000/locations/` working if I just do

```
resources locations
```

but then the nested routes don't work!

How can I get both working?

Many thanks.

**EDIT** rake routes:

```
     location_statistics GET    /locations/:location_id/statistics(.:format)          statistics#index
                         POST   /locations/:location_id/statistics(.:format)          statistics#create
  new_location_statistic GET    /locations/:location_id/statistics/new(.:format)      statistics#new
 edit_location_statistic GET    /locations/:location_id/statistics/:id/edit(.:format) statistics#edit
      location_statistic GET    /locations/:location_id/statistics/:id(.:format)      statistics#show
                         PUT    /locations/:location_id/statistics/:id(.:format)      statistics#update
                         DELETE /locations/:location_id/statistics/:id(.:format)      statistics#destroy
               locations GET    /locations(.:format)                                  locations#index
                         POST   /locations(.:format)                                  locations#create
            new_location GET    /locations/new(.:format)                              locations#new
           edit_location GET    /locations/:id/edit(.:format)                         locations#edit
                location GET    /locations/:id(.:format)                              locations#show
                         PUT    /locations/:id(.:format)                              locations#update
                         DELETE /locations/:id(.:format)                              locations#destroy
              home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)                                 home#index
                   about        /about(.:format)                                      home#about
                 contact        /contact(.:format)                                    home#contact
                    root        /                                                     home#index
```

**EDIT 2** routes file

```
match '/about/' => 'home#about'
match '/contact/' => 'home#contact'

resources :locations do
    resources :statistics
end

get "home/index"
```

**EDIT** 3

My actual error:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:controller=>"statistics", :location_id=>nil}
```

when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/locations/`

Comment: Have you tried "rake routes" ?  If so, post the output.  Also, consider posting your routes.rb file

Comment: does your location_controller.rb have GET and POST actions?

Comment: @PerryHorwich I have an `index` GET actions: `@locations = Location.all(:conditions => ["user_id = ?", current_user.id])`.. do I need a POST?

Comment: POST would be handy if you have a location form that you submit.  You have a route for POST in your rake routes output, so you may want to account for that.  Consider posting the error message you are seeing.

Comment: what kind of error do you get?

Comment: @Lichtamberg see EDIT 3

Comment: please post your code of the link

Comment: The error is probably in your locations index action or view. Can you post the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: have you tried restarting the server? 'rails s'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either use

```
=link_to "Locations", locations_path
```

or

```
# get sure @location is not nil
=link_to "Location Statistics", location_statistics_path(@location)
```